# Drag and repeat values in datagrid (like in Excel) .NET (WPF)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, drag

We want to implement something similar to Excel functionality in (WPF) .NET application in gridview or any other control. The functionality should be similar to the one in Excel where user can select cell and drag mouse down to desired row (number) and value of the first row is copied to all selected rows (drag and repeat values down).

Does any one know if this is possible? I've spent a lot of time searching on Google and didn't find anything useful.

It would be simpler maybe to write VSTO for Excel but we have a lot of (legacy) VBA code and current tests of VSTOs worksheets and add-ins returned "mixed" results whereas mixing VSTOs and VBA it's not best solution for us.

EDIT: payable solution can be also mentioned. :)

Comment: I presume you actually mean "has someone already done this?", in which case likely not if Googling doesn't yield much. That said, it is entirely possible to code yourself.

Comment: I'm actually not very familiar with WPF (XAML). My background mostly came from ASP.NET. I would be very happy if I could get some example to orientate me into the right direction. :)